# Вывод категорий

Tags: php

Как менее нагружённо сделать вывод категорий, на сайте имеется более 100 категорий. Сделать таблицу в MySQL с названием категорий и ид или записать все названия в фаил тхт через запятую, и выводить через массив? Вывод названия категории нужен в новость, в самой новости есть ид категории

Comment: Если вариант с файлом вас не смущает, то наименее нагруженным будет вариант с массивом изначально определённым в php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть мой ответ комуто покажется странным, но оптимизировать что либо нужно тогда, когда это что-либо требует оптимизации.

О какой нагрузке вы говорите? Её нет, а когда появится, начнете соображалку включать в сторону вариантов кеширования.

Смело используйте базу данных, она именно для этого и предназначена, чтобы её использовали.

Плюс ко всему что я сказал выше, стоит добавить, что к вашим категориям, которые хранятся в БД и имеют свой униклаьный id будут привязываться другие таблицы, и вы будете делать выборку данных из них, указывая id категорий, а храня категрии в файле/массиве вы теряете возможность делать выборку чего либо по категориям (связи таблиц имею ввиду)